# Objective-C insert Value at specfied index in mutlidimensional array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have three arrays and all are multidimensional.

What I want is:

```
Array1: 
id=[1,2,3]
name=[a,b,c]
price=[1,2,3]

Array2: 
id=[4,5,6]
name=[d,e,f]
price=[4,5,6]

Array3: 
id=[7,8,9]
name=[g,h,i]
price=[7,8,9]
```

So, how can i merge/combine the ID,Name and Price from array2 and array3, to array 1 so that I get this result:

```
Array1: 
id=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
name=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
price=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I have to do it seperate. Or is it possible like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:array1id aray2id array3id,array1name array2name array3name,array1price array2price array3price, nil];
```

Comment: Do each of the array contains a dictionary named id, name and price which contains another array?

Comment: yes thats correct: array with array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using loops by :

```
NSMutableArray *mergeArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<3; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr1[i]];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:arr2[i]];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:arr3[i]];
    [mergeArray addObject:tempArray];
}

NSLog(@"%@",mergeArray);
```

*Edit:*

The input is:

```
    NSArray *arr1 = @[@[@1,@2,@3],
                      @[@"a", @"b", @"c"],
                      @[@"A", @"B", @"C"]
                      ];
    NSArray *arr2 = @[@[@4,@5,@6],
                      @[@"d", @"e", @"f"],
                      @[@"D", @"E", @"F"]
                      ];
    NSArray *arr3 = @[@[@7,@8,@9],
                      @[@"g", @"h", @"i"],
                      @[@"G", @"H", @"I"]
                      ];
```

The output is :

(
        (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9
    ),
        (
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f,
        g,
        h,
        i
    ),
        (
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D,
        E,
        F,
        G,
        H,
        I
    )
)

Comment: Thaths not exactly what I want. The result should be a multidimensional array

Comment: sorry you were right. I wrote wrong function. That worked very great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should to have 3 `NSMutableDictionary` with 3 `NSArray` in.

You can simply get an union from arrays by `KVC Collection Operators`:

```
NSArray *newArray = [@[array1, array2, array3] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

or if you don't want duplicate:

```
NSArray *newArray = [@[array1, array2, array3] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.self"];
```

So in your case should be something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary dict1 {
    id:NSArray,
    name:NSArray,
    price:NSArray
}
```

and so:

```
dict1[@"id"] = [@[dict1[@"id"], dict2[@"id"], dict3[@"id"]] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

Use this example to understand:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"id":@[@1,@2,@3],@"name":@[@"a",@"b",@"c"]};

NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"id":@[@4,@5,@6],@"name":@[@"d",@"e",@"f"]};

NSDictionary *dict3 = @{@"id":@[@7,@8,@9],@"name":@[@"g",@"h",@"i"]};

NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

mDict[@"id"] = [@[dict1[@"id"], dict2[@"id"], dict3[@"id"]] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
mDict[@"name"] = [@[dict1[@"name"], dict2[@"name"], dict3[@"name"]] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```